# React-Router Browser Router alternate locations?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, vite

Trying to wrap my head around something. When using `react-router` we now use `BrowserRouter` to set up the routes.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    {/* The rest of your app goes here */}
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Now in my case I started up a Vite application with TypeScript. Within that there is an `index.tsx` file and an `App.tsx` file that serves everything. Where would the most logical place be to make the `BrowserRouter` to configure all routing and why one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

The most "logical" place to render the `BrowserRouter` and configure all the routes is in the component/location just above the highest component in the ReactTree that needs to reference the routing context provided by the router. It doesn't matter really if the router is rendered in `index.tsx` or `App.tsx`, so long as the context is properly provided.

For example, if the `App` component used any of the RRD hooks to access the current `location` object or needed to run some logic to check the path, the router would need to be rendered above `App` in the ReactTree.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from './App';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

```
import { Routes, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  const location = useLocation(); // <-- needs routing context to access/use

  ...

  return (
    <Routes>
      ... app routes ...
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

If `App` didn't depend on any routing context then `App` can render the router.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from './App';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <App />
);
```

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        ... app routes ...
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Since you need just one routing context/provider it's common to just render it along with other providers in the index file at the root of the app.

Example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { PersistedProvider } from '../store';
import AuthProvider from '../authProvider';
import App from './App';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <PersistedProvider>
    <AuthProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        ... other providers/wrappers ...
          <App />
        ...
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthProvider>
  </PersistedProvider>
);
```

Comment: That makes sense. So its the routing context that determines where we should place our Browser Router creation. At its most basic level that means understanding if there needs to be access to React Router DOM hooks or other methods to determine the routing then we need the Browser Router placed in a higher component. Since index.tsx renders everything its the ideal location to use Browser Router to avoid any routing context issues even though other components could work too.

Comment: @user19568466 Yes, that's a fair summarization.